# evt.detail.response empty, how to get string from database via iron-ajax?

Tags: node.js, ajax, polymer-2.x

I can't get a simple string from my DB with a nodejs/polymer application.

Here is how I build my request and how in handle it :

```js
_getCommentThread()
{
    this.error = null;
    this.$.commentAjax.url = '/get-comments'
    this.$.commentAjax.method = 'GET'
    this.$.commentAjax.contentType = 'application/json';
    this.$.commentAjax.handleAs = "text";
    this.$.commentAjax.generateRequest();
}
_handleResponse(evt)
{
    console.log('Status : ', evt.detail.status);
    switch (evt.detail.status) {
        
        case 205:
        console.log('Thread de commentaire', evt.detail.response);//This is empty 
        this.commentThread = evt.detail.response;
        break;
        case 204:
        console.log('Commentaitre ajouté correctement');
        break;
        default:
        this.error = 'Unexpected Error';
        break;
    }
}
```

```html
<iron-ajax id="commentAjax" on-response='_handleResponse' on-error="_handleError"></iron-ajax>
```

And on my server here is how I handle it :

```js
app.get('/get-comments', function(req, res) {
  maria.getCommentThread(function(err, data){
    if(err){ 
      console.log('Request : SELECT commentaire :: ERROR');
      res.status(400).send(err).end();
    }
    else{
      console.log('Request : SELECT commentaire :: OK');
      var str = Object.values(data[0]);
      console.log('thread', str[0]);// It contains exactly hat I want as a String
      res.status(205).send(str[0]).end();//the str[0] contains the string I want to sens to the front-end, 
    }
  });
});

//The next function is in another file and work perfeclty well
exports.getCommentThread = function (callback){
    var c = init(),
    query ="SELECT commentaire FROM mission WHERE id_mission = 1"

    c.query(query, function(err, res)
    {
        if (err){
            c.end();
            callback(err, null);
        }
        else{
            c.end();
            callback(null, res);
        }
    });
}
```

When I log the the server response, the status is OK (205 as I want it) but the event.detail.response is empty !!!! And I can't figure out why ?

Can someone help me ?

Comment: What if you reply with 200?

Comment: The reason I ask about 200 vs 205 is this note: "Browser behavior differs if this response erroneously includes a body on persistent connections" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/205). Does Node.js use HTTP keep-alive? If so, it's persistent, and the response should not have a body (not the word "erroneously"). Or that's how I read the MDN doc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it worked when reply with 200 :) Lesson : Do not play with status code